# How do I write a SQL query for a specific date range and date time using SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to write a query that will get all the rows in a specified date range and time range.

For example, I want to query all the rows from 5:00PM on 16-Sep-2010 to 9:00AM on 21-Sep-2010.

Any ideas as to how the query should be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Infact this worked for me

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM myTable
 WHERE CAST(ReadDate AS DATETIME) + ReadTime BETWEEN '2010-09-16 5:00PM' AND '2010-09-21 9:00AM'
```

Answer (score 35):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '09/16/2010 05:00:00' and '09/21/2010 09:00:00'
```

Comment: If there cultural problems (may be your application runs different cultures) this syntax may be cause some problems. If you have problems, you can format date like this: 09/16/2010 05:00:00 => 20100916050000'

Comment: @bahadir arslan, I would prefer to use '09/21/2010 09:59:59' to get more accurate results.

Comment: @gs_guy, you are right but we are not sure exact requirement, until 09 am or until 10 am?

Comment: Also include the AM/PM designation or specify military time.

Comment: @Adrift, 20100916050000 format is 24 hour format, so no need to add AM/PM

Comment: @bahadir arslan, you would be correct if he wanted values from 5:00 AM, but he wants them from 5:00 PM.

Comment: @Adrift you are right, i am sorry ;) i think 20100916170000 will be ok for this situation.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have explained my question in detail. Anywayz guyz, I've got three coulmns in my table, "Value", "ReadTime", "ReadDate". Where ReadTime and ReadDate having data types of time and date respectively. Now keeping this in mind that I've separate columns for date and time, how would I achieved the results as asked in the main question.

Comment: The only safe formats for datetime literals in SQL Server (or at least historically) are: "YYYYMMDD", "YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss" and "YYYY-MM-D'T'hh:mm:ss:mil" (where 'T' is the literal letter T). All other formats are subject to culture issues.

Comment: I have a similar kind of situation where I need to fetch dates stored in the field DATE where the month is JAN or any other month. I need the query to do this operation. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE DATE BETWEEN '03/10/2014 06:25:00' and '03/12/2010 6:25:00'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
use DBName

select *
from TABLE_NAME A
where A.date >= '2018-06-26 21:24' and A.date <= '2018-06-26 21:28';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DATE(readingstamp) 
BETWEEN '2016-07-21' 
AND '2016-07-31' 
AND TIME(readingstamp)
BETWEEN '08:00:00'
AND '17:59:59'
```

simply separate the casting of date and time

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT Value, ReadTime, ReadDate
FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE CAST(ReadDate AS DATETIME) + ReadTime BETWEEN '2010-09-16 17:00:00' AND '2010-09-21 09:00:00'
```

EDIT: output according to OP's wishes ;-)

Comment: Thnx but I need the result set in the same format i.e "Value","ReadTime","ReadDate" ( I don't want to merge date and time )

Comment: @eumiro, What if I want to get all the rows for each date no matter that day record is present in the the db or not? regards.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the US date format is different from the UK.  Using the UK format, it needs to be, e.g.

```
--                                  dd/mm/ccyy hh:mm:ss     
dbo.no_time(at.date_stamp) between '22/05/2016 00:00:01' and '22/07/2016 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score -2):

```
"SELECT Applicant.applicantId, Applicant.lastName, Applicant.firstName, Applicant.middleName, Applicant.status,Applicant.companyId, Company.name, Applicant.createDate FROM (Applicant INNER JOIN Company ON Applicant.companyId = Company.companyId) WHERE Applicant.createDate between  '" +dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString() + "'and '"+dateTimePicker2.Text.ToString() +"'";
```

This is what I did.