# Using whereRaw on pivot relationship model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder

I need to be able to use a `whereRaw` on a pivot table relationship to get all the data for today.

For example, this is my model

```
public function comments(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Comments', 'user_comments', 'user_id', 'comment_id');
}
```

Which works great, it gets me all the data I need.

But then how would I use a `whereRaw` statement on this model? So if i needed to loop through every comment that was created today, but the comment date field is stored in `Y-m-d H:i:s` format so i need to trim off the time, how would i do it? Trying to do something like this

```
foreach($user->comments->whereRaw('DATE(comment_date) = DATE(NOW())') as $comment){
   echo $comment->content;
}
```

But it just returns

> [BadMethodCallException]
>     Method whereRaw does not exist.

Is it not possible to use the `whereRaw` builder like this?

Also how would i do this through a relationships relationship?

For example, if my comments had a relationship to a table called comment_location and I wanted to do a `whereRaw` on the comment Location relationship like this

```
foreach($user->comments as $comment){
  foreach($comment->commentLocation->whereRaw() as $location){
    echo $location->name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `$user->comments()->whereRaw...`. Note `()` after the comments

Comment: **$comment->commentLocation** cahnge to **$comment->comment_location()**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `$user->comments` which is an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` but you should be using `$user->comments()` which is instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany` and you can add your query builder function

Fixed Code:

```
foreach($user->comments()->whereRaw('DATE(comment_date) = DATE(NOW())')->get() as $comment) {
   echo $comment->content;
}
```

Comment: Mind going into more detail as to *why/how* this fixes the issue at hand?

Comment: Ahh right ok! How would i do this if I was accessing a relationships relationship? Please see edited question

Comment: See this question accepted answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760956/how-do-i-write-a-sql-query-for-a-specific-date-range-and-date-time-using-sql-ser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760956/how-do-i-write-a-sql-query-for-a-specific-date-range-and-date-time-using-sql-ser). It must be helpful for you

Comment: also add **->get()** after **->whereRow()**