# SQL Between Dates as an Object

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get only the dates between 2018 and 2020 but still get 2017... not sure if I'm missing something obvious but would love some help.

[image]

Comment: (1) Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...? (2) Provide your query and data as text, not as images (2) What is the datatype of column `joined_at`?

Comment: If this is Access database and joined_at is date/time field, use # instead of apostrophe delimiter. Regardless, if field is not date/time, need to convert.

Comment: @forrestGump Welcome! There are multiple answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760956/how-do-i-write-a-sql-query-for-a-specific-date-range-and-date-time-using-sql-ser/3760974 Its nice to be able to google things and get answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use correct date formats:

```
where joined_at >= '2018-01-01' and
      joined_at < '2021-01-01'
```

This assumes that `joined_at` is stored as a date/time value.  Most databases support date constants in the YYYYMMDD format.

If `joined_at` is stored as a string, you should fix your data model.  How you do this exactly depends on the database.